# How to insert row in database only if all fields are not identical to another row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm not used to dealing with MySQL, so please forgive me if the syntax or the terms I use are incorrect.

I'm building a form for an event held on multiple dates where people can reserve their place on a set date, for themselves plus up to 9 other people from the same address. When a user submits the form, I grab the address, postal code, the date they selected and first and last name of every person registered.

I'm trying to save them in MySQL but I want to avoid duplicates *if all the values already exist* in a row.

Every solution so far revolved around setting a unique or primary key, but I can't set one because I could have

- Multiple people with the same name
- Multiple people from the same address
- A user registering for multiple dates

Basically, I want to avoid a duplicate based on all the fields at once.

Let's say I have the following `participants` table:

```
id |    nom      |   prenom  |  adresse  | code_postal  |  e_date

1  |    Doe      |   John    | 1, Main   |  H0H0H0      | 15-04-2016
2  |    Doe      |   Jane    | 15, Main  |  A1A1A1      | 15-04-2016
```

If I get another entry like so:

```
3  |    Doe      | John      | 1, Main   | H0H0H0       | 15-04-2016
```

it should *not* insert it (but could replace row 1, since all columns have the same values), but if I get something like

```
3  |    Doe      | John      | 1, Main   | H0H0H0       | 16-04-2016
```

then it should insert it in the table, because at least one column is different.

Same thing with

```
3  |   Smith     | Dan       | 1, Main   | H0H0H0       | 16-04-2016
```

The only two queries I've tried that didn't generate any errors were

INSERT IGNORE

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO participants(nom,prenom,adresse,code_postal,e_date) VALUES ('$nom','$prenom','$adresse','$codePostal','$date')"
```

INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
INSERT INTO participants(nom,prenom,adresse,code_postal,e_date) VALUES ('$nom','$prenom','$adresse','$codePostal','$date') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nom='$nom', prenom='$prenom', adresse='$adresse', code_postal='$codePostal', e_date='$date'
```

Both queries go through but add duplicates. What did I miss?

I'm a bit out of my depth here, so any suggestion is appreciated. Please let me know if my explanations weren't clear. Thanks!

---

Thanks to @frédéric-h-fournier, I ended up with this working solution:

```
$checkQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowCount FROM participants WHERE nom='$nom' AND prenom='$prenom' AND adresse='$adresse' AND code_postal='$codePostal' AND e_date='$date'";
$checkResult = mysql_query($checkQuery);
if($checkResult){
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($checkResult);
    if($row[0]==0){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO participants(nom,prenom,adresse,code_postal,e_date) VALUES ('$nom','$prenom','$adresse','$codePostal','$date')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());  
    }
}
else{
    die("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Both `INSERT IGNORE` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should work. If it's inserting a dupliate row then you are missing the unique indexes on those columns.

Comment: *Hm...* what about an INSERT ... SELECT and use a WHERE clause with an `!='x'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a UNIQUE INDEX KEY or/and in your PHP code you should query your DB like this

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowCount FROM TABLE WHERE nom = 'Doe'"

And after

if($query['rowCount'] > 0){
    // err
}
```

Ah et aussi, si tu créer un UNIQUE INDEX KEY assure toi de le faire dans ton code PHP comme ci-dessus vu que ta requêtes va te retourner un erreur!

Comment: Thanks! There were a couple pieces missing but your answer pointed me in the right direction. What I did was a `SELECT COUNT` query checking all my columns. If the query goes through, I do a `mysql_fetch_row($result)` and if that return 0, I send my INSERT query. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a unique index for the columns that must never be duplicate.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uix_pub_name ON publishers(pub_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I normally do that is by querying the DB to check if the values already exist. You always have to identify what is the uniqueness of a table. It looks like in your case, the uniqueness lies on the following columns: id |    nom      |   prenom  |  adresse  | code_postal  |  e_date.

In that case, before doing an insert, you could do a select statement:

```
select * from participants where id = $id and nom = $nom and prenom=$prenom and adresse = $adresse and code_postal = $code_postal and e_date=$e_date;
```

If that returns something, don't insert. If it doesn't return anything, then you can go ahead and insert.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a column that contain result of any hash function (SHA1 or MD5) of your row. It can be hash result of concatenated string of all field value in a row.

So, before inserting, calculate the hash result and look up from your table if the hash result had been exist or not. If it's not exist, insert it.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can run select query with all the values and see if any record is returned.

2) insert data only if no record is returned.